# Jmeter - restart session after expired continually for 10 hours

Tags: session, jmeter, session-timeout

My current environment: JMeter v2.11, remote Oracle 12, JDK 7

I have a soak test to generate in Jmeter and I'm unsure quite how to do what I need.

Essentially - I have a recorded script for 200 users to login to a web application within 1 thread group but I need to keep this going for 10 hours.

The http sessions will expire after 15mins, so I'm a little lost how to make the session restart once the http session has expired.  I have had a think, I've played with 'Loop Count' settings on the thread group, I've googled for an answer, and I've searched on this forum but I haven't found anything that I can see is relevant (although I did find stuff that was quite interesting).

My current workings are as follows:

`Thread Group - Number of Threads --> 200, Ramp Up --> 50, Loop Count ---> 1
--HTTP Request Defaults
--HTTP Cookie Manager
--Recording Controller
---HTTP Request - Login Page Launched
---HTTP Request - Username Input
---HTTP Request - Password Input
---HTTP Request - Login Button selected
---Some listeners`

As with my previous posts - I am very grateful for any guidance anyone can provide.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter works as follows:

It starts all defined virtual users (threads) within the bounds of ramp-up period provided. In your case it means that JMeter adds 4 new virtual users each second for 200 seconds.

Each thread executes samplers upside down as fast as it can. when sampler finishes its work and doesn't have more loops to iterate it is being shut down.

If you want your scenario to run over 10 hours set "Loop Count" to "Forever" and specify "Duration" on Thread Group level to be 36000 seconds as per image below:

[image: Thread Group Scheduler]

In this case you'll get 200 concurrent users executing defined samplers for 10 hours.

Another option to specify test (or particular test part) duration is using [Runtime Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller)

Just in case if you need not 200 concurrent users but 200 requests per second, take a look at [Constant Throughput Timer](http://How%20to%20use%20JMeter's%20Throughput%20Constant%20Timer) documentation.

Also JMeter acts on protocol level, it doesn't actually type anything into inputs or clicks buttons so my expectation is that you scenario should look as follows:

- Open Login Page (HTTP GET)
- Perform Login (HTTP POST)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Dmitri T.  thanks for that.  @Dmitri T.  I have 2 questions if thats ok.  Where you state 'Each thread executes samplers upside down' - I have read this before and cannot visualise what this means - can you clarify?  Also - where  you state 'adds 4 new virtual users each second for 200 seconds' - can you explain why it runs for 200 seconds?  After thinking, I would've thought it would run for 50 seconds, rather than 200 as 200 is the no. of threads.  Finally - in regards to your comment about the http methods - yep I understand, the input password/username are actually https posts.  ta

Comment: I ran a test based on above and it wasn't giving me the results I was looking for as it appears to loop through the requests until the duration has expired.  Obviously I wasn't as clear/concise as I needed to be in the original question.  I will update the original question details.  Thanks

Comment: I've created a new query as the purpose of my query has now changed and the answer to my question was still informative.